# on clicking button row isn't getting added

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my HTML page I have a dynamic input table, in which when button is clicked another row gets added. I think the JavaScript is fine and everything is fine but after all the row isn't getting added after clicking.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = 1;
  $('#add').click(function() {
    a++;
    $('#dynamic_pdfield').append('<tr id="row' + a + '"><td style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="preportno[]" value="<?php echo $report ?>"></td><td><input type="text" name="pending[]" placeholder="Work Pending" class="form-control name_list" ></td><td><input type="text" name="pendingqty[]" placeholder="QTY." class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + a + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
  <div class="form-group">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_pdfield">
      <tr>
        <th style="display:none;">Report No.</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>QTY.</th>
        <th>Add or Remove</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="preportno[]" value="<?php echo $report ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="pending[]" placeholder="Work Pending" class="form-control name_list"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="pendingqty[]" placeholder="QTY." class="form-control name_list" /></td>
        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">+</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <center>
      <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-success">
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

I could not figure out what I am going wrong on?

Comment: I can see the row is added correctly from the Javascript. So what is the issue you're facing exactly? Is this about submitting the form? If so, please show your code that takes care of getting the data and sending it to the backend

Comment: @AndreaOlivato He said he's facing a problem with adding the row so I don't think It has something to do submitting to the backend.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the javascript console? If so then what are those errors?

Comment: Your code seems to work once jQuery is included; I chose not to add that to your code when I created the snippet, since that appears to fix the problem. If you've included jQuery in your own code then it *should* work, and the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't reveal explicitly, I have to add not including JQuery library will conclude with an `error object` on the console with the "message" property "ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

Then if you take a look at the embedded code snippet below, you may see the only thing added to both of the rows are ids that user entered as input params. With the intended ids declared within input fields, and then using via `string interpolation` inside the `append` function, it concludes the intended behaviour.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = 1;
  $('#add').click(function() {
    a++;
    $('#dynamic_pdfield').append(`<tr id="row' + a + '"><td style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="preportno[]" value="<?php echo $report ?>"></td><td><input type="text" name="pending[]" placeholder="${desc.value}" class="form-control name_list" ></td><td><input type="text" name="pendingqty[]" placeholder="${qty.value}" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + a + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>`);
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field">
  <div class="form-group">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_pdfield">
      <tr>
        <th style="display:none;">Report No.</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>QTY.</th>
        <th>Add or Remove</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="preportno[]" value="<?php echo $report ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="desc" name="pending[]" placeholder="Work Pending" class="form-control name_list"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="qty" name="pendingqty[]" placeholder="QTY." class="form-control name_list" /></td>
        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">+</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <center>
      <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-success">
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```